# Certification Error in NetBeans, even though ".CER" file was added to KeyStore

Tags: java, rest, maven, netbeans, keystore

I added my CER file to my keystore by issuing the following command:

```
"keytool -import -storepass [insert store pass] -noprompt -alias [insert alias] -keystore "[insert directory]\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\security\cacerts" -trustcacerts -file [insertname].cer"
```

I am trying to make a REST call in a Java application. My REST call works when I run the application in Eclipse but when I run the **same** application in NetBeans, I get the following error message which implies I did not add the CER file to the keystore:

```
"PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"
```

I copied the application from NetBeans to Eclipse directly to narrow down the issue and it worked perfectly fine in Eclipse so I figure it's not a coding problem but a configuration problem somewhere in NetBeans. Anyone have any idea how I can fix this? How come the application works in Eclipse but not in NetBeans? I've been trying to look around but cannot find anything.

If it's also helpful, I am using a Maven Java Application project.

FYI: I am using NetBeans IDE 8.2 Patch 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your application run from NetBeans is using the same JDK.

Check the JDK referenced in the libraries of your project.
Or make sure NEtbeans itself is started using the right JDK.

The [OP dunce1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2938794/dunce1) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144620/certification-error-in-netbeans-even-though-cer-file-was-added-to-keystore/48144756?noredirect=1#comment83279521_48144756) it was not the case:

> Looks like NetBeans was using the JRE environment in JDK where as Eclipse was using non-JDK JRE environment for runtime

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. There's one JDK installed on my machine and from what I read online, Eclipse uses its own compiler and uses the jre for runtime. I have two folders in my java directory : jdk1.8.0_45 and jre1.8.0_45

Comment: @dunce1 Use a process explorer to check what actual JDK/JRE is used when lanuching your project from Kubernetes. It seems it does not use the one JDK your are referring to in your question.

Comment: Looks like NetBeans was using the JRE environment in JDK where as Eclipse was using non-JDK JRE environment for runtime. I was unable to add the certificate to the JRE folder under JDK (got access denied even though I was admin) so ended up replacing the folder with the non-JDK JRE folder and now it's working.

Comment: @dunce1 is it possible you were not able to update the JRE because it was already being used by a process, meaning the jre/lib/security/cacerts was kept by an handle?

Comment: Not sure. I did close all my Java applications and going into administrative mode before updating the key. I also tried changing the permission settings as well.